# Internet Explorer strips HTML from JSON response

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit a form via AJAX and receive a JSON response:

```
$('#'+searchFormView.form.form.id).ajaxForm({
    dataType:'json',
    success:This.renderSearchResults,
    error:This.error
});
```

The HTTP response body:

```
{
"grid":{
    "headers":[
        "Image","Additional","data","button"
    ],
    "rows":[
        ["<img src=\"\Path_to_image\" alt=\"picture\">",
         "Additonal",
         "data",
         "<button>Button text<\/button>"
        ],
        [Some more of these arrays]
    ]
}
}
```

Chrome and FF are totally OK with this. It renders fine. IE strips the HTML out of the data value by the time it hits the success method:

```
renderSearchResults:function(data){
    console.log(data.grid.rows[0][0]);
    // Render the grid.
}
```

The result of the console log in IE:

```
Log:
```

If I watch the local variables while the success method runs:

```
"{
    \"grid\":{
        \"headers\":[
            \"Image\",
            \"Additional\",
            \"data\",
            \"Button\"
        ],
    \"rows\":[
        [\"\",\"Additional\",\"data\",\"Button text<\\/button>\"],
        ...
```

As you can see, the HTML tags are gone (curiously, the  tag is still there).

Is this supposed to be an XSS protection?

How do I get around it?

Comment: XSS protection? I doubt it. For some reason M$' safety mechanisms are not only weird but are not safe at all and make developers lifes really hard. :D

Comment: I guess you could encode the "<" and ">" to HTML Number, for example. Then, maybe IE wont take your tags out.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Which versions of IE are you having problems with?

Comment: @invertedSpear jQuery 1.9.1 The issue is happening in IE8 and IE9. I assume it's present in 7 as well.

Comment: @jean-c-lourenco, wouldn't encoding the < and > make the page output the tags as text rather than the actual button and image I'm going for?

Comment: IE doesn't change the response from an XMLHTTPRequest in any way. Most likely, the jQuery abstraction is doing this as a side-effect of what you're calling "ajax". Is your POST going cross-domain?

Comment: @EricLaw No, it's staying on the domain. IE is clearly acting differently from every other browser. And the change is happening somewhere between the request and the success callback. The only thing happening between there is the jQuery ajax logic which is changing nothing in Chrome or FF. (sidenote: I tend to call all my Aynchronous Javascript and XML processes "ajax")